# comparing two ordinal variables by different groups

Tags: ordinal-data, descriptive-statistics

I have two groups, like students above 40 and between 24-40 (variable name :student)

Also I have 2 different ordinal variables like (education: primary through Phd) and life satisfaction ( 1: bad through 5:excellent).

I want to find out whether there is any difference between two students groups in terms of education and life satisfaction.. I also want to investigate subgroup details like: students above 40 and with a primary education have bad life satisfaction etc.. )

Which test should I apply?

Comment: Maybe a wilcoxon test?

Answer (score 0):

To test the null hypothesis that the distribution of education is the same in the >40 and the 24-40 age groups and that the distribution of life satisfaction is the same in the two age groups, the appropriate test is the [Mann-Whitney U test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) (also known as the Wilcoxon rank-sum test).

Extra info: The test can be performed in R with the `wilcox.test()` function, with x and y specified as the education / life satisfaction values of the two samples. Make sure that `paired = FALSE` (as you want to test two independent samples; this is the default value).

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/wilcox.test

Comment: You can also use the generalization of the Wilcoxon test, the [proportional odds model](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo).  And note that you are not analyzing age correctly.  Counting everyone the same when their age can vary greatly is not correct.  Age should be kept continuous, then you can use Spearman's $\rho$.